# AOSP / Android Source code indexing tools

Tags: android, c++, indexing

I'm searching for tools that would allow me to index and navigate within AOSP source tree a little bit easier.

My team works mostly at the lower level (so C and C++), but we interface with Java quite a bit. Currently we use:

- ack-grep,
- ctags,
- cscope.

Since we're building a whole platform, we're not limited to just our code, but sometimes also need to understand better what's happening inside Android.

I currently make an attempt to use OpenGrok -- indexing is far from being done and the log is already swollen from git warnings.

The tools we currently use are hardly a convenient way to navigate the code. I would like to reach out for Android hackers wisdom - how do you navigate the code?

Comment: Using OpenGrok (albeit a terrible UI) provides the best option IMO for exploring the AOSP tree. Remember to index the trees with the repository history information (.svn, .git, etc.) intact to be able to use the History and Annotation features. http://androidxref.com is a great place to see OpenGrok on AOSP in action; however, newer versions of opengrok have additional features such as filetype filtering (via dropdown box).

Comment: Android M repo has a little over 700 repositories. Does that mean that I would need to index each of the 700 repositories separately?
My problem with OG is mostly about the volume of junk it creates - millions of tiny files - the implications are actually observable - both in terms of space wasted and time needed by OS to access the cluttered folder.

On separate note, i don't exactly care about history, but so far my attempts to kill it with env variables have had no effect...

Comment: I repo sync the AOSP branch and index once for all of them (usually an overnight job). It should crawl through each. If you remove all the .git dirs recursively through AOSP before you index, it may save you a decent bit of time.

Comment: I love the "off topic" closure and guideline.

"Off-topic because whatever". Meets the guidelines for SO memes.

TL;DR for this is: there are no good solutions. Use AS where possible, otherwise there's really not much out there.

Answer (score 0):

For the Java part [Android Code Search](https://cs.android.com/) is quite a blast. Unfortunately, I think it's "online-only" And also, for the low-level (C/C++) stuff things need to evolve a bit.